# Sum hours from timestamp

Tags: sql

I have a `user_id` field and `time` field. The `time` field is `timestamp` datatype.
A user id may have many log times. 
I want to find the sum between the time in hours and minutes for the user.

I have managed to convert to hours and minutes but I cannot sum the hours for each id. 
Below is the code i have used.

```
select user_id, to_char (time_loged)as "Totalhours "
from logtable
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: A timestamp represents a point in time. Normally, you'd expect a SQL database to represent duration with the INTERVAL data type. The difference is that adding two intervals that *look* like this makes sense: 3:00 + 2:00. But adding two points in time that look like that doesn't; "3 o'clock plus 2 o'clock" is *literally* nonsense. "3:00" (meaning 3 hours) looks exactly like "3:00" (meaning 3:00 am), but they have *very* different meanings.

Comment: I am using oracle sql. so what is the datatype i should used for time worked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Oracle example of converting timestamp with to_char() or to_date(). You can remove day formats leaving time formats only separating time to minutes, seconds then sum them up as numbers with to_number()...

```
SELECT to_char(to_timestamp ('2013-02-14 10:07:47.000' , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'),'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') start_date
 FROM dual
/

  SQL> 14-FEB-2013 10:07:47


SELECT to_date(to_char(to_timestamp ('2013-02-14 10:07:47.000' , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'),'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') start_date
 FROM dual
 /

  SQL>  2/14/2013 10:07:47 AM


SELECT to_char(to_timestamp ('2013-02-14 10:07:47.000' , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'),'HH24') start_date
 FROM dual
 /

 SQL> 10

  SELECT to_number(to_char(to_timestamp ('2013-02-14 10:07:47.000' , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'),'MI')) minutes 
   FROM dual
  /

  SQL> 7
```

In your case data is timestamp already while I had to convert my date to_timestamp in my code. Simply ignore to_timestamp convesion and use to_char(), to_number()...

All my examples are always tested. Copy and paste last example as is to see the difference with your code. Read my comments...

Comment: I received errors when i tried to_number the data..Here is the statement ive used.select id, to_char(to_number (time,'HH24:MI'))as "Total Hours Worked"
from test;

Comment: @mariodelcy - please look at my last example - copy it, replace my date with your date, remove conversion to_timestamp if not needed, leaving all the rest. Or you can copy/paste as is to see the result, then simply replace my hardcoded date with yours and your table... All examples are tested. You cannot convert 'HH24:MI' to number. You need to separate time to HH24 first, then MI. Besides, you maybe using a keyword - time. Rename it to tm...