# calculate/sum timestamp in sql

Tags: sql, db2-luw

I am stucking by calculating the timestamp,how can i calculate/sum on different timestamp, example as below

```
Time (Timestamp in one column)
***********************
0:00:01
0:00:08
0:00:12
0:00:38
0:01:04
2:04:49
15:48:38
23:30:59
7:05:52
8:17:29
```

I want to show the sum(timestamp) in `hh:mi`.Any help?

Comment: do you have date along with time stamp or just only time stamp??

Comment: Hi smn, having only timestamps

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874811/sum-hours-from-timestamp

Comment: thank you providing the details I tried what is given But the database is db2.

Comment: Hi Muse, adding to your comment data type varchargraphic which can convert it to (SUM(RTRIM(hour(TK.STATUSTRACKING)))+ ( SUM(RTRIM((minute(TK.STATUSTRACKING)))))/60) but still i am facing some error, i will if it is solve

Comment: Well, what have you tried?  There are functions `HOURS(...)`, etc.... Given your sample data, what should the result be?  Note that you can't use `TIME` as the output type, as that's strictly time-of-day (stops at 24 hours, essentially).

Answer (score 0):

i can tel you in postgresql you can do like

```
postgres=# select time '05:00' - time '03:00';
 ?column? 
----------
 02:00:00
(1 row)
```

dont know how much this can help you

Answer (score 0):

This example works on DB2 when the values being added are TIME columns (as shown in original question). The trick is to convert the times to elapsed seconds, which are much easier to add up.

```
WITH origTbl (origTime) AS (VALUES
( TIME( '0:00:01' ) ),
( TIME( '0:00:08' ) ),
( TIME( '0:00:12' ) ),
( TIME( '0:00:38' ) ),
( TIME( '0:01:04' ) ),
( TIME( '2:04:49' ) ),
( TIME( '15:48:38' ) ),
( TIME( '23:30:59' ) ),
( TIME( '7:05:52' ) ),
( TIME( '8:17:29' ) )
)
,
totSeconds( secs ) AS (
SELECT SUM( MIDNIGHT_SECONDS( origTime ) ) 
FROM origTbl
)
SELECT RTRIM( CHAR( secs/3600 ) ) || ':' || 
LPAD( RTRIM( CHAR( MOD(secs, 3600)/60 ) ), 2, '0' ) || ':' ||
LPAD( RTRIM( CHAR( MOD(secs, 60) ) ), 2, '0' ) AS totHMMSS FROM totSeconds
;
```

---

```
TOTHMMSS
-----------------
56:49:50

  1 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: Thanks Fred for your response,but as above data which used as sample if Varchargraphic datatype column inserting/holds only HH:MI:SS format data, I need to calculate the total column data,this column holds status wise timestamp data, hope you get it